# Java Null Dereference when setting a field to null - Fortify

Tags: java, fortify

Fortify is complaining about a Null Dereference when I set a field to null:

```
String sortName = null;
if (lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0) {
   sortName = lastName;
}
sortOptions.setSortField(sortName);  <--  Fortify Null Dereference
```

Fortify's analysis trace says:

```
Assigned null: sortName
Branch taken: if (lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0)
Dereferenced: sortName
```

I could try:

```
if (sortName == null)
   sortOptions.setSortField(null);
else
   sortOptions.setSortField(sortName);
```

But that seems really silly. Anyone have experience with this one? I'd prefer to get rid of the finding vs. just write it off.

Comment: If passing a null value into `setSortField` causes a NullPointer then passing an explicit null in is going to do the same thing

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: what happens if, just for testing, you do `String sortName = "" ;`

Comment: Added Fortify's analysis trace, which is showing that the dereference of sortName is the problem. We set fields to "null" in many places in our code and Fortify is good with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What fortify do not like is the fact that you initialize the variable with `null` first, without condition, and then change it.

this should work:

```
String sortName;
if (lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0) {
   sortName = lastName;
} else {
   sortName = null;
}
sortOptions.setSortField(sortName);
```

(Or use the ternary operator if you prefer)

This way you initialize `sortName` only once, and explicitely show that a `null` value is the right one in some cases, and not that you forgot some cases, leading to a var staying `null` while it is unexpected.

The *Null dereference* error was on the line of code `sortName = lastName;` not the call of the setter : fortify do not want you to conditionnally change the value of a variable that was set to `null` without doing so in all the branches.

Comment: I'll try this solution. Unfortunately our Fortify scan takes several hours to run. I'll update as soon as I have more information... thx Thierry

Comment: This solution passes the Fortify scan. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Thierry's answer works great. This also passes Fortify's scan:

```
Optional<String> sortName = Optional.empty();
if (lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0) {
   sortName = Optional.ofNullable(lastName);
}
sortOptions.setSortField(sortName.orElse(null));
```

Comment: You should be able to use `Optional.of` instead of `ofNullable` here, because you have already checked that it's not null.