# Java Null Dereference when setting a field to null with Fortify

Tags: java, fortify

Fortify is complaining about a Null Dereference when I set a field to null:

```
ApplicanteeTO applicanteeTO = null;
    
if(applicanteeNRIC != null && !applicanteeNRIC.equals("")){
      if(!populationId.equals(Constants.POPTYPE1) && !populationId.equals(Constants.POPTYPE2)) {
          applicanteeTO = //retrieve from db
      }
}
        
log.debug("applicanteeTO details: " + applicanteeTO);

if(applicanteeTO != null){
    // do logic
}
```

What I am trying to do is initialize ApplicanteeTO object with null, then check if it is under certain population type, populate it. If not, leave it as null. However, Fortify is throwing me this warning in the report:

```
The method initForm() in SingleReplacementController.java can crash the program by dereferencing a null-pointer on line 110.
```

And that line is pointed to the logger. I am trying to eliminate the warning raised from Fortify. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Can I do it in such way?

```
ApplicanteeTO applicanteeTO;
    
if(applicanteeNRIC != null && !applicanteeNRIC.equals("")){
      if(!populationId.equals(Constants.POPTYPE1) && !populationId.equals(Constants.POPTYPE2)) {
          applicanteeTO = //retrieve from db
      } 
} else {
     applicanteeTO = null;
}

log.debug("applicanteeTO details: " + applicanteeTO);

if(applicanteeTO != null){
    // do logic
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The second version is equivalent to the first.  There's no reason for you to set a variable to `null` that you know already has that value.  Whatever your problem, it has to be something else.

Comment: I am getting this from Fortify: The method initForm() in SingleReplacementController.java can crash the
program by dereferencing a null-pointer on line 110. And that line is pointed to the logger. I am trying to eliminate the warning raised from Fortify

Comment: So it's complaining about `applicanteeTO` being `null` when the line `log.debug("applicanteeTO details: " + applicanteeTO);` is run?  There's nothing wrong with that.  It's not great form, but I believe that it's well defined in Java as appending the String "null" in the case where `applicanteeTO == null`. - I don't see anything technically wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes it is highlighted in that line. I tried to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448074/java-null-dereference-when-setting-a-field-to-null-fortify But I am not sure if my proposed solution will actually eliminate the Null Deference warning for Fortify or not

Comment: How about changing the log line to `log.debug("applicanteeTO details: " + ((applicanteeTO == null)? "null" : applicanteeTO);` ? - this should give you equivalent behavior, but should satisfy Fortify if it's complaining about concatenating `null` to a String.

Comment: But the Null Deference warning is due to the part where I initialize applicanteeTO to null isn't it? If I removed the initialization to null, the second part of the IF is complaining to initialize the variable. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227864/discussion-between-steve-and-hyperfkcb).

Answer (score 1):

If Fortify is complaining about the `log.debug` line, then it (Fortify!) is incorrect.  Concatenating a string with `null` is safe.  It converts the `null` to a `"null"` and concatenates that instead.

So you have a couple of choices:

- Ignore the warning.
- Suppress the warning (if Fortify allows that).
- Rewrite that statement; e.g. as follows:

  ```
  // This ugly code is to stop Fortify complaining
  log.debug("applicanteeTO details: " + 
            (applicanteeTO == null : "null" : applicanteeTO));

  // Or use if / else
  ```

With a bit of luck, the JIT compiler will generate code that doesn't do multiple null checks on `applicanteeTO`.  But that is version dependent.

If things are as stated, and this really is a Fortify bug, then you should:

- Check to see if there is a newer version of Fortify that fixes the bug.
- Report the bug to Fortify.

Comment: Sure sure thanks! But can I check with you for another scenario? For instance, I got object1 and object2. I wanted to populate object1 based on object2 to fetch from database. Eg. Object object1 = null; object1 = service.method1(object2.nric); In this case, Fortify is throwing warning stating program might crash when derefenced from object2.nric. So will it eliminate the warning if I do in this way: if(object2 != null) { object1 = service.method1(object2.nric); } ?

Comment: You sure you wrote that correctly?  No mention of what `object2` is initialized to ...

Comment: Yes, object2 is initialized to null also. It will go thru business logic to populate but there are chances that the if else condition won't meet so it will remains as null

Comment: Then, yes Fortify is correct, and yes your proposed fix should keep Fortify quiet.  (But you could just try it for yourself before asking!)

Comment: Sure sure because I am not authorized to rescan the project. I am only tasked to fix the warning so I have to fix then wait till next week for rescan then fix again.

Comment: That sucks.  Sounds like someone in your organization needs to know that this affects your ability to work efficiently.